# How to have sub-columns of a column in a matrix report?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Need to have sub-columns in a column of a matrix report.

The structure is as follows:

```
            Lease   |      Rental
          MTD | YTD |     MTD |  YTD
         -----+-----+---------+-----
Segment       |     |         |
```

My doubt is asto how to have the structure of MTD and YTD (sub-columns)
within Lease and Rental (column). Any ideas on how to incorporate the same 
would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Co-Oracler

Answer (score 1):

The exact solution will depend on your data model but alas you have neglected to provide us with tables.  So this is only an indication of a possible solution.  The pertinent technique is the use of CASE in the query projection.

```
select 
       segment
       , sum(case ( when type = 'LEASE' and t_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'MON') then
                t_qty else 0 end) as lease_mtd
       , sum(case ( when type = 'LEASE' then
                t_qty else 0 end) as lease_ytd
       , sum(case ( when type = 'RENTAL'  then
                t_qty else 0 end) as rental_mtd
       , sum(case ( when type = 'RENTAL' and t_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') then
                t_qty else 0 end) as rental_ytd
from your_tablee 
where t_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY')
```

The TRUNC() on sysdate is a neat trick, which produces the date indicated by the format mask.  So the 'MON' mask produces the first day of teh current month and the 'YYYY' produces 01-JAN of the current year.

Answer (score 0):

From the db point of view the "sub-columns" get selected just as normal columns, it is up to the tool you use for actually formatting the report how to create a layout as you described.